Jenkins echoes only the name of the environment variable, not the actual value
Started by user unknown or anonymous
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\test
[test] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins7973539064156672133.bat

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\test>echo Hello 
Hello

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\test>echo ${BUILD_ID} 
${BUILD_ID}

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\test>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS

As you can see, the build was successful, but the environment variable "BUILD_ID" value did not show.

In batch scripting you need to use %BUILD_ID% syntax.
